# Set data types for specific rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas it's quite easy to set a datatype for the entire dataframe or for specific columns.
I'm having troubles finding documentation on changing only specific rows data type.
My dataframe is something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"idx": ['Unit', 'From', 'To'], 
                   "Length": ['Meter', 32.5, 65], 
                   "Weight": ['Kg', 7, 44.7]})
df.set_index("idx")
```

[image]

By default pandas would set everything as object (string).
I would like the 1st row to be treated as **string** and the 2nd and 3rd row to be treated as **float**.

Is this possible?

Comment: dont think that is possible. Pandas operates in a column wise fashion. if you change the 1st row to string, then all the values in the `Length` column become object dtype.

Comment: Look at how you created the dataframe, you pass string value , panda could not know it is float ~

Comment: Rows do not have a datatype, columns do.

Comment: @BEN_YO that was my mistake in creating the example, I'm gonna edit it. If I pass them as float will they be preserved as float at row level, even tough in the same column there exist also string?

Comment: Adding explanation

Answer (score 1):

The way here still can not make the column back into `float` still `object` , since `pandas` is store the data type per `column` not per `index`(row)

```
df.update(df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce'))
df
Out[75]: 
     Length Weight
idx               
Unit  Meter     Kg
From   32.5      7
To       65   44.7
df.applymap(type)
Out[76]: 
               Length           Weight
idx                                   
Unit    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
From  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
To    <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
```

Update

when you change the input , the data and cell it self already change to correct type, `object` for column mean mix type not string

```
df.applymap(type)
Out[80]: 
               Length           Weight
idx                                   
Unit    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>
From  <class 'float'>    <class 'int'>
To      <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>
```

Comment: My example was clearly a simplification of the real problem. When I read data from csv or excel pandas converted them to objects (I guess because there is at least one object for each column?)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know object meant mixed type, I've always assumed just string!

Comment: @Leonardo nope that is mix type in your case ~

Answer (score 0):

In your case use `df.iloc`:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['m','1','2.6','4.7'],
    'B': ['e','3','4.7','1.2']
})
df.iloc[1:] = df.iloc[1:].astype(float)
print(df)
```

Comment: The `dtypes` *are still object* in the resulting frame

Comment: But without dtypes, you can apply calaculation operations e.g. sum() on those rows